# Ext3 partition doesn't mount on Snow Leopard using MacFUSE

Tags: macbook, ubuntu-10.10, ext3

I'm dual-booting OS X and Ubuntu on a Macbook 4,1. I'm trying to mount my Linux partition in OS X. I installed MacFUSE 2.0.3,2 and fuse-ext2-0.0.7 on Snow Leopard 10.6.5. I created the directory /Volumes/Ubuntu and tried to mount the disk there using the command: fuse-ext2 /dev/disk0s4 /Volumes/Ubuntu/

This is the output I get:

fuse-ext2: version:'0.0.7', fuse_version:'27' [main (../../fuse-ext2/fuse-ext2.c:324)]
fuse-ext2: enter [do_probe (../../fuse-ext2/do_probe.c:30)]
fuse-ext2: Error while trying to open /dev/disk0s4 (rc=13) [do_probe (../../fuse-ext2/do_probe.c:34)]
fuse-ext2: Probe failed [main (../../fuse-ext2/fuse-ext2.c:340)]

Any clue what's going wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely FUSE is not able to work with ext4 partition. I guess it may have only support for ext2 and ext3. Your Ubuntu is installed with ext4 partition.

Here is a link that puts support for ext4 partition in FUSE https://github.com/gerard/ext4fuse however make sure to mount readonly partition as it is still buggy.